# usingSession in webdriver js

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

Does anybody know how to use usingSession() in Webdriver js?
I have a webdriver session initialized by another process and I would like to connect to that session using webdriver js API.

**Edited:**

I ended up connecting to an already established session by "jumping" a layer in Webdriver Js (using inner API let's say):

```
function createDriver(port, session){
    var base = require('selenium-webdriver/_base'),
        executors = require('selenium-webdriver/executors');

    var url = base_url+':'+port;
    var WebDriver = base.require('webdriver.WebDriver');
    var executor = executors.createExecutor(url);
    return WebDriver.attachToSession(executor, session);
}
```

The sad thing is that it seems that you just can't attach to an already existing session if you use the "builder.js" at root level (node_modules\selenium-webdriver) which is the one that comes "by default" when doing things like this:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
    build();
```

That builder.js at that mentioned root level allows you to import webdriver.Builder which is NOT the same as one provided by the builder.js located in (node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\builder.js). This last one is much more complete and lets you do more stuffs. (like attaching easily to an already existing session)

Comment: Selenium or webdriver.io?

Comment: Webdriver js: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs which AFAIK is the official binding from Selenium folks for Js.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. You had tagged your question correctly (`selenium-webdriver` <=> language binding from Selenium), but I wasn't 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following with protractor to attach to an existing browser session.

https://gist.github.com/tristanstraub/d1c36ddaf9dcced570a6

It uses the same solution as yourself, but hooks itself in before createSession, which I believe is called from build().